# How do I create a Play! Framework web project with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, playframework

Is there a Maven archetype out there to create a Play! Framework Java web application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no Maven archetype. Play tries to distance a bit from standard Java EE practices, and it provides a full stack including dependency management.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [community contributed extension](http://www.playframework.org/modules/maven-head/home) to help you with this.

Comment: I was looking for a Play archetype for Maven, question updated

Comment: You should ask that in another question, I answered the original question already.