# Is it possible to create a standalone JAR web app with Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, maven-2

I'm trying to create a standalone JAR application, which will be executed from command line like this:

```
$ java -jar foo.jar --port=8080
```

I want to use Play Framework. Is it possible to create something like this? I want to use Java and Maven. I want to stay away from that "activators" or downloading of Play. Just plain old simple Maven dependencies. Possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a Play! Framework web project with Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710710/how-do-i-create-a-play-framework-web-project-with-maven)

Answer (score 3):

To stay away from `activator` and Play download just on your dev-machine call cmd: `./activator dist` (`activator.bat dist` for Windows) it will create a ZIP file in the `target/universal/` directory containing scripts for both: Unixes and Windows within the `bin` directory.

So you can launch your app like (unix sample, after unzipping)

```
/your-app-dir/target/universal/your-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/your-app -Dhttp.port=8080
```

Of course, nothings prevents you from creating additional shell script/BAT file for simplicity this path

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here it is possible. [Look at the documentation (Default SBT layout).](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Anatomy)
Quote from the play 2.4.0 documentation:

> You also have the option of using the default layout used by SBT and Maven. Please note that this layout is experimental and may have issues. In order to use this layout, use disablePlugins(PlayLayoutPlugin). This will stop Play from overriding the default SBT layout [...]

I haven't tested it, but I think this is a good point to start at :)

P.S.: Let us know if it is possible!